# Regex expression for reptitive groups

Tags: php, regex, cookies, key-value, regex-group

This one is for the regex experts. I am trying to write a Regex expression for a key value pair for Cookies, which has a `=` in front of key and a `;` at the end of the value.

So, basically a `key=value;` should pass. The string could be repititive, for which it should pass too. like `key1=value1; key2=value2;` should pass,

However anything except for this should fail. Like `key=value1;key=value2;;` should fail as it has 2 `;` at the end. And also strings like `key==valu1;;`, `=value;`, `key=;`, `key=value` should fail.

So far, I have been learning about grouping in regex and came up with this `(?<pat>([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*?=[a-zA-Z0-9\- :]+;))`. But this is not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: is this what you're after. [`^(?<pat>([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?=[a-zA-Z0-9\- :]+?;)+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/TZXGQs/1/)

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt work. This doesnt work at all.

Comment: I think i have covered what your question has as example, can you state where it is failing ? can you post some more examples ? let me see

Comment: Sorry this seems to be working , but not for all cases.

Comment: [`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/TZXGQs/2/) seems to work. did you checked the demo ? it covers the cases you mentioned in question, can you elaborate what do you mean by all cases ?

Comment: Are you trying to extract all individual key-value pairs or just attempting to validate entire string?

Comment: Just validating....works fine.... thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe,

```
^(?:\b[a-z0-9]+=[a-z0-9]+\b;\s*)*$
```

or some similar expression might work OK.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZe0Jp/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/^(?:\b[a-z0-9]+=[a-z0-9]+\b;\s*)*$/s';
$str = 'key1=value1; key2=value2;';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```